# Adding node to linked list

Tags: c#

I want to implement simple Linked list and adding items and its seems that my `Add` function get into endless loop and i don't know why

```
public class IntNode
{
    private int _value;
    private IntNode _next;
    public IntNode(int val, IntNode n)
    {
        _value = val;
        _next = n;
    }
    public int getValue()
    {
        return _value;
    }
    public IntNode getNext()
    {
        return _next;
    }
    public void setValue(int v)
    {
        _value = v;
    }
    public void setNext(IntNode next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public string ToString()
    {
        return _value.ToString();
    }
}

    public class IntList
    {
        private IntNode _head;
        public static int count;

        public IntList()
        {
            _head = null;
            count = 0;
        }
        public IntList(IntNode node)
        {
            _head = node;
        }

        public void Add(IntNode node)
        {
            if (_head == null)
                _head = node;
            else
            {
                for (IntNode p = _head; p.getNext() != null; p.getNext()) { }
                _head.setNext(node);
                count++;
            }
        }

        public void ToString()
        {
            IntNode cur = _head;
            while (cur.getNext() != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(cur.ToString());
                cur = cur.getNext();
            }
        }
    }
```

main

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IntList list = new IntList();
        list.Add(new IntNode(5, null));
        list.Add(new IntNode(2, null));
        list.Add(new IntNode(8, null));
        list.Add(new IntNode(1, null));

        list.ToString();

    }
```

Comment: Why not keep a reference to tail?

Comment: Did you mean `p = p.getNext()` in the `for` loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the increment step in the `for` loop.  It needs to be `p = p.getNext()` not simply `p.getNext()`.   The latter just calls the `getNext` function and does nothing with the return which means `p` is never modified and hence the loop doesn't make any progress

```
for (IntNode p = _head; p.getNext() != null; p = p.getNext()) { }
```

The next problem is you are not actually moving `_head` or using the `p` value.  Hence you haven't actually found the place to insert.  What you need is something like the following

```
IntNode p = _head;
while (p.getNext() != null) { 
  p = p.getNext();
}
p.setNext(node);
```

Comment: @zerkms no, the compiler has to assume that `getNext` has a side effect that needs to happen hence it won't remove it

Comment: @zerkms It's irrelevant. The code is just plain wrong at the first place.

Comment: @Ondrej Tucny: it is irrelevant indeed, I was just curious about compiler behaviour

Comment: @zerkms correct, C# does essentially no interprocedure analysis.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (IntNode p = _head; p.getNext() != null; p.getNext()) { }
```

You're not using `p` anywhere, and not doing anything in the loop body. Can you spot your problem?

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't assign the result of `getNext()` anywhere:

```
for (IntNode p = _head; p.getNext() != null; p.getNext()) { }
```

Second, you even don't use the last node anywhere. In fact, you even couldn't, because `p` doesn't exist outside of the `for` loop…

Advice: Keep a reference to the *last* node as well and make your life simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop never ends because `p` is not incremented.

It should be easier for you if you keep a reference to the last inserted item. For example :

```
private IntNode _lastNode;

public void Add(IntNode node)
{
    if (_head == null)
        _head = node;
    else
    {
        if (_lastNode == null)
            _lastNode = _head;

        _lastNode.setNext(node)
        _lastNode = node;
    }
    count++;
}
```

You won't have to loop through nodes each time you try to add a node.

Comment: Just for convenience: it's common to name it `tail`